# Select and use page template not only on the start page, but also in the page library

Tags: template, sitepages

here's my problem. I have created a page template and I get it displayed when I open the menu "new" on the start page (see screenshot).

[image: new menu on startpage]

This site "Template Wiki-Eintrag" can be used and it works perfectly.If I create pages using this template, they will be stored in the standard library, which also contains news pages etc.

[image: Menu for selecting a page template]

So far so good, but when I am in my library and want to add a new page, I only get my content types of the library displayed.

[image: new menu on the websitesites library]

How can I create new pages from this library with my template?

I thought that I could simply edit the content type that is displayed in the menu.

[image: content type]

I then simply uploaded as a document template the .ASPX page I created in my website library - the previously mentioned "Template Wiki Entry" page. 
But when I now try to create a new "Websiteseite" via the "New menu", I get the following error:

[image: error]

I would be happy about your solutions and suggestions / tips!

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to create new page from a document library?<br>

Comment: In this special document library are the pages stored... so when I browse the different pages, I want also to create some new page with my template. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Please refer to the link [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-do-a-custom-modern-page-library/m-p/116981). I think this may help you.

Comment: Yes this is the right main topic, but it does not cover my problems with the template... :(

Comment: This is a common problem, there are several different places in SharePoint to initiate a "New Page" which generates a new item in the SitePages library, but most of them only use the default page template, the only place that gives you a chance to choose from amongst templates, is the button on the home page.

Comment: Is it possible to include a template in the menu of the site page library / make it available to users?